# How to fill correcltly this area graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I have the data frame  `total`, with 3 `col` and 1356 `row`:

```
       Var1   Var2   value
1
2
3
...
...
1356
```

the first colum is a date vector, the second is an index, and the third column are values. 
I plot area graph with ggplot, the code is:

```
ggplot(total,aes(x=Var1,y = value), stat = "bin")+geom_area(aes(fill=Var2))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#CC6666", "#9999CC"))+
  labs(x="Tempo(mesi)",y="Biomassa",title="Biomassa modelli")+
  theme_bw()+ theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

the result is: 
[image]

The problem is that the area of the graph are one above the other, and in my data there are some period which overlapping in the two series. 
Where i wrong in the code to plot `total` data? 
The expected plot is like this, but with fill area:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some example data so that we can reproduce your graphs? Use `dput()` to add data to your question.

Comment: Maybe try `position = "identity"` inside the `aes()`.

Comment: I tried geom_area(position = "identity") but the result is all graph in the same color

Comment: Why isn't the line graph good enough exactly?

Comment: with position ="identity" ggplot fill all area in the same color, i think that i need to insert also color or fill in the argument of geom_area

Comment: I don't think it's filling everything the same color. Rather, `res_cing` is probably "underneath" `res_istat`. Reverse the factor order for this variable and see if `res_cing` appears. Or add `alpha=0.5` inside `geom_area` and see if `res_cing` appears.

Comment: So appear only res_cing now and not res_istat

Comment: Now ok..thank you!!!